# .htaccess add timestamp at end of url

Tags: .htaccess

I have this code in .htaccess  that add date and hour after  url

```
example.com/post1.html?2015022015
```

here is code

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}?%{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}%{TIME_HOUR} [L,R=302,NE]
```

Is there a way if time changed and when user visit link to change it to the current time
    example.com/post1.html?2015022015

so to delete ?2015022015  and to add new

2. Second problem is is there a way dont apply this to

   example.com/wp-admin

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(?!wp-admin) %{REQUEST_URI}?%{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}%{TIME_HOUR} [L,R=302,NE]

RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}##%{QUERY_STRING} ^([^#]+)##\1
RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}%{TIME_HOUR}##%{QUERY_STRING} !^([^#]+)##\1
RewriteRule ^(?!wp-admin) %{REQUEST_URI}?%{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}%{TIME_HOUR} [L,R=302,NE]
```

So the rules have been changed to ignore wp-admin via `^(?!wp-admin)` and the second rule is added with the condition that the query string starts with the current year and month, but not the day or hour.

Comment: all is ok great answer but 
if page is example.com/page/2/ ?201502211929
then i get error This webpage has a redirect loop Error code: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS